# Is creating new thread for displaying PyQt message box several time a good practice?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am trying to create and run a new thread each time I want to pop a message box from main thread.  Wondering if this code below will cause memory leak or even a good practice.  If it can be improved, how to?

```
class UIThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, message):
        print "UIThread init(). msg = " + message
        this_thread = threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        this_thread.daemon = True
        self.message = message
        self.qtapp = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.w = QWidget()

    def run(self):
        print "UIThread running"
        result = QMessageBox.warning(self.w, 'WARNING', self.message, QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if result == QMessageBox.Yes:
            print 'Yes.'
        else:
            print 'No.'

        sys.exit(self.qtapp.exec_())

...
    messagebox = UIThread("Test")
    messagebox.start()      

....
    messagebox = UIThread("Test 2")
    messagebox.start()      

....
    # will pop up more message boxes throughout the program
```

Comment: move to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/  ?

Comment: I assume, since you are creating a `QApplication` over and over again that this message box is the only use of Qt? (aka it is not a GUI application?). Regardless, you are likely to run into issues creating many `QApplications`. You should only interact with the Qt library from one thread (typically the main thread, though it might work if *everything* is in a secondary thread). Basically, what you are doing is very dodgy.

Comment: Yes, the message box is the only use of Qt.  It is not a GUI app.  The main thread is used for heavy math calculation.

Answer (score 4):

No it's not good practice. You should only do GUI stuff, including showing message boxes, from the main thread. Use signals and slots to communicate with the main thread, which can show the message box and provide a response for your secondary thread.

Here's a simple example where a worker thread signals the main thread to show a message box, then checks the `responses` dictionary for the message box response (basic dictionary operations are thread safe). This example should also work for multiple threads as the responses are keyed under the thread name.

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import threading, time, sys


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, app):
        super(Worker, self).__init__()
        self.app = app

    def do_stuff(self):
        thread_name = threading.current_thread().name
        self.app.responses[thread_name] = None
        self.app.showMessageBox.emit(thread_name,
                                     'information',
                                     'Hello',
                                     'Thread {} sent this message.'.format(thread_name))
        while self.app.responses[thread_name] is None:
            time.sleep(0.1)
        print 'Thread {} got response from message box: {}'.format(thread_name, self.app.responses[thread_name])


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    showMessageBox = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str, str, str)
    def __init__(self, sys_argv):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(sys_argv)

        self.responses = {}
        self.showMessageBox.connect(self.on_show_message_box)

        self.worker = Worker(self)
        self.thread = QtCore.QThread()
        self.worker.moveToThread(self.thread)
        self.thread.started.connect(self.worker.do_stuff)
        self.thread.start()

    def on_show_message_box(self, id, severity, title, text):
        self.responses[str(id)] = getattr(QtGui.QMessageBox, str(severity))(self, title, text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MainWindow(None)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a sample!